# Android react native recyclerview

Tags: android, react-native

I am attempting to migrate a native android project over to react native to make it cross platform. I am currently using recyclerview and a bit confused about what the closest React Native library is.

Answer (score 5):

This is what you should be looking at: https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview.
The one referred to in first answer isn't cross platform. Flipkart's recyclerview works on Android/iOS/Web

Comment: this has the best performance, but only with a full width, when there is a gird view for example 4 item in a row or more, that time `dropped so far` goes over 100 and `stutters dropped so far` too.

Answer (score 4):

The RecyclerView of React-Native is FlatList.
Is very easy to use. You have all info here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html
Greetings!